How to write into stdin of spawned child
Let's say I have some Node.js questions:
ask-questions.js
const arrQuestions = [
  "what is your age?",
  "what is your gender?",
  "where do you live?",
];
let ind = 0;

const total = arrQuestions.length
process.stdin.on("data", (data) => {
  if ( ind >= arrQuestions.length) {
    console.log("process - NO MORE QUESTIONS - EXIT!");
    process.exit();
  }
  process.stdout.write(`${arrQuestions.at(ind++)}\n`);
});

process.stdout.write(`${arrQuestions.at(ind++)}\n`);

module.exports = {
  arrQuestions,
};

When I run node questions.js and enter 2\n for each answer:
What is your age?
2
What is your gender?
2
Where do you live?
2
process - NO MORE QUESTIONS - EXIT!

How do I write to the stdin of this process with the following code?
// spawn-questions.js

const path = require("path");
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const arrUserInput = [];
const childProcess = spawn(
  "node",
  [path.join(__dirname, "ask-questions.js")],
  { env: process.env }
); 


// These do nothing. 
childProcess.stdout.write("answer 1 from spawner\n");
childProcess.stdout.write("answer 2 from spawner\n");
childProcess.stdout.write("answer 3 from spawner\n");

childProcess.stdin.write("answer from spawner\n");
childProcess.stdin.write("answer from spawner\n");
childProcess.stdin.write("answer from spawner\n");

// expect exit


I want to automate the user input above to trigger the next question. How do I do that?

Why do you require("./ask-questions")? That's also running the whole script.

@jonrsharpe to test it. At the moment I'm just trying to understand how to write back to it before I can put it into a test.

But the output you're seeing is from that require, not the spawned child process (whose stdout you don't do anything with). So of course writing to the child process's stdin doesn't seem to advance the program - that's not the input it's waiting for.

@jonrsharpe How else would I import the 'spawn' command. Otherwise 'spawn' is undefined.

...what? You're not requiring spawn from ask-questions, you're requiring it (correctly, although destructuring would be more idiomatic) from child_process. You're requiring arrQuestions from ask-questions, which again is running that script, then trying (and failing, check the stderr) to spawn node path/to/node-questions.js.

@jonrsharpe Ah I see what you are saying. I have a typo in this code. I'll correct it. The code is correct, the question is wrong. Bare with me., Just updated. Same problem

...you're still requireing the other script as well as spawning it. And childProcess.stdin.write is how to write into the stdin of the spawned child.

@jonrsharpe  I'm not spawning from it. Its just an import. I removed it to avoid confusion.

I never said you were spawning from it, but requireing it does run the script, because all of your running code is at the top level. You should probably just restructure the code to separate the concerns and make it more testable. But to proceed on the path you're going I'd suggest your next step is ensuring you actually see what's coming out of your spawned child process (tip: writing to its stdout makes no sense, but reading from it might be helpful) - again, stdin.write is how to write to its stdin so your title is already covered.

@jonrsharpe = how is  const childProcess = spawn("node",[path.join(__dirname, "ask-questions.js")]) requiring it?

...it's not, which is why the behaviour of what you've posted is completely different now that you've removed the const { arrQuestions } = require("./ask-questions"); that is glaringly obviously what I was talking about, unambiguously requiring the module as it does.

There's a few things you can do differently.
Firstly, childProcess.stdout.write isn't going to do anything, because it's a readable stream, not a duplex.
Second, you want to wait for the process to actually spawn before you start trying to pipe into it's stdin, you can do this via the event on the child process.
Third, you should wait for the process to prompt you with a question before sending a response, you can do this by listening to stdout.
Fourth, whenever you try to spawn a child, you should make sure to listen for an error on it. In this case, for example, an error would occur if node isn't in the path.
Fifth, it's a good idea to watch for the exit code on a spawned process for in-process errors (which usually cause exit with a non-zero code).
Putting it all together:
const path = require("path");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const arrUserInput = [];
const cp = spawn(
  "node",
  [path.join(__dirname, "ask-questions.js")],
  { env: process.env }
); 

cp.once('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});
cp.once('spawn', () => {
  cp.once('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log(`Child exited with ${code || signal}`);
  });
  cp.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
  cp.stdout.on('data', (question) => {
    let answer;
    switch(question) {
      case 'a': 
        answer = 'b';
        break;
      case 'c':
        answer = 'd';
        break;
      // etc
    }
    cp.stdin.write(answer+'\n');
  });
});

Additionally, for your child process you're better of using the native readline module which will handle the nitty gritty for you.
i.e.
const readline = require('node:readline/promises');

const arrQuestions = [
  "what is your age?",
  "what is your gender?",
  "where do you live?",
];

async function main() {
  const rl = readline.createInterface(
    { input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout }
  );

  for(let question of arrQuestions)
    await rl.question(question);

  rl.close();
}

// Run the process if called as main script
if(require.main == module)
  main();
// Otherwise export questions
else
  module.exports = arrQuestions;



ok thanks for the responses. I've answered my own question.
childProcess.stdin.write() works only for the first instance, but not subsequent instances synchronously. I had to put in a timeout of atleast 3+ ms depending on my operating system performance.
Also, worth noting, that the original script console.log does not output here. I had to add my own console.log on this spawner page to help me see it was actually progressing through each question.
childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('Parent: question=', data.toString());
})

example-with-set-timeout
const path = require("path");
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const arrUserInput = [];
const childProcess = spawn(
  "node",
  [path.join(__dirname, "ask-questions.js")],
  { env: process.env }
);

childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('Parent: question=', data.toString());
})

const minTime = 3;

setTimeout(() => {
  childProcess.stdin.write("answer 1 from spawner\r\n");

  setTimeout(() => {
    childProcess.stdin.write("answer 2 from spawner\r\n");

    setTimeout(() => {
      childProcess.stdin.write("answer 3 from spawner\r\n");
    }, minTime)
    
  }, minTime)


}, minTime)



When using recursion and a timeout I noticed that time gap wasn't enough and I was seeing console.log of the parent twice  before the answer.
example-with-set-timeout-on-recursion
const path = require("path");
const { arrQuestions } = require("./questions");
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const childProcess = spawn(
  "node",
  [path.join(__dirname, "ask-questions.js")],
  { env: process.env }
);


childProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log("Parent: question=", data.toString());
});

const minTime = 15; // This number had to be atleast 15 ms
const runAnswer = (ind) => {
  if (ind < arrQuestions.length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const answer = `answer ${ind + 1} from spawner\n`;
      console.log("Answer: ", answer);
      childProcess.stdin.write(answer);
      runAnswer(ind + 1);
    }, minTime);
  }
};
runAnswer(0);

Best solution is actually wait for the question to be asked and then answer it.
const path = require("path");
const { arrQuestions } = require("./questions");
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

const childProcess = spawn(
  "node",
  [path.join(__dirname, "ask-questions.js")],
  { env: process.env }
);

const answers = new Array(arrQuestions.length).fill("answer");
console.log("answers", answers);
let ind = 0;

childProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log("Parent: question=", data.toString());
  if (ind < arrQuestions.length) {
    const answer = answers[ind++];
    console.log("Parent: answer=", answer);
    childProcess.stdin.write(answer);
  }
});


